# Proving the bilinearity of a certain form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I have a question regarding a paper:

let $φ, ψ: ℝ^3 \to ℝ$ two linear maps with $φ(v)= 〈a,v$〉 and $ψ(v)=〈b,v$〉with $a,b ∈ ℝ^3$.
We define the map with $ℝ^3 \times ℝ^3 \to ℝ$ by

$$s(v,w):=  φ(v) * ψ(w).$$

I need to show that s is a bilinear form and determine the transformation matrix of s regarding the canonical basis of  $ℝ^3$.

I have no clue how to do this, so help would be much appreciated

Comment: You are sure you have no clue at all about the fact that it is a bilinear form ? My personal opinion (maybe I am wrong) is that you haven't tried... and you want us to do it at your place. So I vote to close this question.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to prove it. I have looked into my books and couldn't find a proof,,,

Comment: I have tried to do it with    a=φ  and b= ψ                                                            
(1)  s(a(v)+a'(v), b(w)) = s(a(v), b(w)) + s(a'(v), b(w))[

(2) s(a(v), b(w)+b'(w)) =  s(a(v), b(w)) +  s(a(v), b'(w))

(3) s(\lambda *a(v), b(w))=\lambda s(a(v), b(w))

(4) s(a(v), b(w)*\lambda)=s(a(v), b(w))*\lambda           however this is not a proof ...

Comment: Good ! At last you show us where you are blocked. Maybe your problem is a problem of notations misunderstanding ; in particular,  I don't understand at all what you mean by $a(v),b(w)...$ : you should write $s(v,w):=\phi(v).\psi(w)$. To prove left-linearity, you have to prove $s(v+v',w)=s(v,w)+s(v',w)$ and $s(av,w)=as(v,w)$ (where $a$ is a real number)  i.e., you  have to prove $\phi(v+v').\psi(w)=\phi(v).\psi(w)+\phi(v').\psi(w)$ which is immediate because $\phi$ is linear. Do you agree ? etc. etc.

Comment: So I have the following conditions:       
ϕ(v+v′).ψ(w)=ϕ(v).ψ(w)+ϕ(v′).ψ(w) and ϕ(v).ψ(w+w')=ϕ(v).ψ(w)+ϕ(v).ψ(w') as well as : ϕ(av)*ψ(w)=a*(ϕ(v).ψ(w))  and    ϕ(v)*ψ(wa)= (ϕ(v).ψ(w)) * a  to proof. The problem is just I don't know how to do it. If there is like a useful website where I can get some tips (not the full solution of the proofs) it would really help me.

Comment: But the proof of $ϕ(v+v′).ψ(w)=ϕ(v).ψ(w)+ϕ(v′).ψ(w)$ is evident: it suffices to insert  $=(ϕ(v)+ϕ(v′)).ψ(w)=$ between the LHS and the RHS (due to the linearity of $\phi$ on the left, and due to the property of factorization in $\mathbb{R}$ on the right.

Comment: Thanks you! Do I actually also need to proof  ϕ(v).ψ(w+w') or is ϕ(v+v′).ψ(w) enough?

Comment: No, you just have to say "the right linearity is justified in the same way as the left linearity".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your second question, write your bilinear form like this

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}v_x & v_y&v_z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_x\\a_y\\a_z\end{pmatrix}}_{\langle v,a\rangle}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}b_x& b_y&b_z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_x\\v_y\\v_z\end{pmatrix}}_{\langle b,v\rangle}=$$

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}v_x & v_y&v_z\end{pmatrix}}_{V^T}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}a_x b_x&a_xb_y&a_xb_z\\a_yb_x&a_yb_y&a_yb_z\\a_zb_x&a_zb_y&a_zb_z\end{pmatrix}}_M\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}v_x\\v_y\\v_z\end{pmatrix}}_V$$

and $M$ is the transformation matrix. It is a rank one matrix because all columns of $M$ are proportional to its first column.